# Puzzle needs a name

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, grid-deduction, nonogram

Inspired by @Stiv's [*This new puzzle type needs a name*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a60644%20title%3a%22new%20puzzle%20type%20needs%20a%20name%22) series, what is the name of the puzzle below?

[image]

Start by solving the (quite tough) Nonogram, then apply some [grid-deduction-deduction](/questions/tagged/grid-deduction-deduction) and discover its name!

Comment: Nice puzzle Jens :) Pretty sure I know what its name is and how to obtain it - if I get time tonight I'll write it up, otherwise I'll leave it for someone else to enjoy! +1

Comment: @Stiv Thanks! Seeing as half the puzzle is semi-plagiarized from one of your puzzles (remember that plagiarism is the greatest form of flattery!), I'm not surprised. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Thanks for the opportunity to answer one of these myself!) This puzzle is a:

> **NONOLINK**

Both @jafe and @Rand'alThor have already solved the first-stage nonogram. The next thing to notice is that:

> Each different colour represents a specific number. In particular, taking the colours in 'rainbow order' and starting with Red = 0, we also have Orange = 1, Yellow = 2 and Green = 3. What type of puzzle might a grid containing only values 0-3 be? Why, a **slitherlink**. The resulting grid can then be resolved according to the rules of slitherlink (a line forming one continuous loop; each numbered cell describes the number of edges of that cell which are part of the loop), like so:
>  [image]

To extract the puzzle's name, we then...

> ...see which letters in the original grid end up on the path:
>
>  [image]
>  If we start top-left and follow the loop clockwise, we read off the letters **NONOLINK** - a portmanteau of **NONO**GRAM and SLITHER**LINK**, the two puzzles that have been combined here...
>  <sub>Note that the OP has also left a little 'Easter egg' in the unused letters, which anagram to *SLITHERGRAM*, an alternative portmanteau choice for this puzzle's name...</sub>

Comment: Augh, I considered this but only with green=0, yellow=1 etc. which led to a quick contradiction. Nice job!

Comment: @jafe Gargh, that happens so often! I feel your frustration...

Comment: Well done! There is a little easter egg with the unused letters. Can you find what they spell? :)

Comment: @Jens Looks like the unused letters are rot13(na nantenz bs FYVGURETENZ)

Comment: You're 12 hours late to the party @Avi ;-) (See the last paragraph of my answer...!)

Comment: @Stiv Ah, well caught :)

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer

Completed nonogram:

> [image]

No idea what to do next...

Comment: Argh! I finished the nonogram first, and your answer popped up while I was categorising the letters :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Don't worry, I'm drawing a blank on the second part...

Comment: +1 Amazingly fast solve of the nonogram! :)

Answer (score 5):

Nonogram solution is as follows:

> [image]

Now some letters

> (S, N, A, M, I, K, R, H, I) are *not* bordering two different colours,

while others

> (L, R, N, O, E, O, N, T, G) are on colour borderlines.

Noticeably, that second set of letters

> includes N, O, N, O, G, R, ... and E, L, T.

The first set looks like it might be

> an anagram of some Japanese [grid-deduction](/questions/tagged/grid-deduction) name, like, I don't know, Narshmiki or something.

Other types of puzzle that come to mind, looking at this:

> ANAGRAM (from the letters formed); POLYOMINOES (the shapes of the coloured pieces in the grid); TETRIS (could those coloured pieces be falling down?)

Comment: +1 Amazingly fast solve of the nonogram! :)

Comment: I love me a good nonogram puzzle :-) Had way too much practice with these.